# align lightning input inline label to the right

Tags: lightning, lightning-inputfield

I've tried a few things and no matter what I do I cannot get the lightning inline label to align to the right instead of the left. I would like the First Name and Last Name label to align to the right instead of the left.

[image]

```
<div class="slds-box">
  <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
      <lightning:input label="First Name:" type="text" value="{!ct.FirstName}" variant="label-inline"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
      <lightning:input label="Last Name:" type="text" value="{!ct.LastName}" variant="label-inline"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

How about font-weight, color, font-size, label width? Is any of that customizable? Lightning seems to make these type of cosmetic changes very difficult.

Comment: That's an unusual requirement and not possible by default with base component, you need to hide the input label with `variant="hidden"` and add your own label in html after the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after playing around, I tried using a grid with separate labels and label hidden inputs.

Try this:

```
<div class="slds-box">
  <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">

      <div class="slds-form-element ">
        <div class="slds-grid">
          <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
            <div class="slds-form-element__label" style="text-align: right; width: 100%; margin-top: 0.25rem;">Text Input</div>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
            <lightning-input label="First Name:" type="text" value="test" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
    
      <div class="slds-form-element ">
        <div class="slds-grid">
          <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
            <div class="slds-form-element__label" style="text-align: right; width: 100%; margin-top: 0.25rem;">Text Input</div>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
            <lightning-input label="First Name:" type="text" value="test" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Caspar Harmer. Getting it to look the way you want in lightning can definitely be difficult. Sincerely appreciate the help